# lightning:dualListbox show error Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined after Spring'18

Tags: lightning

Thanks in advance!
   In winter'17 I writed a component in my lightning org.
BUT
   When I open it this Spring,it occurs 
[image]

Here is the key code:

```
enter code here

<lightning:dualListbox sourceLabel="可选字段" selectedLabel="已选字段" options="{!v.leftoptions}" onchange="{!c.handleChange}" value="{!v.rightoptions}" />
```

the JS code:

```
initialize: function(component, event, helper) {
    var options = [];
    var action = component.get("c.initAllFields");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var result = response.getReturnValue();
        if (state == "SUCCESS") {
            helper.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            component.set("v.allFields", result);
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                options.push({ 'value': result[i].fieldAPIName, 'label': result[i].fieldName });
            }
            component.set("v.leftoptions", options);
            helper.log(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.leftoptions")));
        } else {
            helper.log('xxx!');
        }
    });

handleChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var choosedFields = [];
    var selectedOptionsList = event.getParam("value");
    helper.log('SelectOptionList===' + selectedOptionsList);
    var rightOpts = component.get("v.rightoptions");
    var allFields = component.get("v.allFields");
    for (var i = 0; i < rightOpts.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < allFields.length; j++) {
            if (rightOpts[i] == allFields[j].fieldAPIName) {
                choosedFields.push(allFields[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    helper.log('选中了=' + JSON.stringify(choosedFields));
    component.set("v.choosedFields", choosedFields);
},
```

The Helper Code:

```
 ({
//电销模板log
log : function(msg) {
    console.log('电销模板:' + msg);
},

//显示提示信息
showToast: function(title, messgae,type) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": title,
        "message": messgae,
        "type":type
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
},

//导航到某页面
navigateToURL: function(url) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": url
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

})

And I have tested the component find that the errror occours when use **lightning:dualListbox**. Any body can help?Is the problem about LockerService?

Comment: Please include here the code which attempts to call `parentElement`. Do not share your code using gists if it will fit here.